# Text not visible in text box where datepicker jquery is used

Tags: jquery, jsp, datepicker

I need to create an EDIT_PROFILE.jsp page. It has a date of birth textbox field with a

> date picker jquery.

```
 <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob" value="<%=user.getDob()%>"/>
```

I am picking user DOB from the database using USER_MODEL POJO :- "user".

Problem is that text is not visible in this textbox , Jquery is working fine but data from database is not visible for this textbox only.

Do I need to remove this jquery or is there any way I can get this work?

Comment: make sure the date format is same for both. yy/mm/dd is default for datepicker, can change like... datepicker. $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

Comment: *but data from database is not visible* what data do you mean?

Comment: i meant to say that I am populating user model object for database as follows while(resultset.next()) { usermodel obj=new usermodel() , then usermodel.setDOB(rs.getString("dob") and then return usermodel... in jsp I am populating it as <input type="text" value=<%=usermodel.getDOB()%>

Comment: @Fahad I tried your solution too but still its not showing data of usermodel.
I have alter datepicker format to "d m y" still not working